# Ram Size Using Quartz Scheduler

Tags: quartz-scheduler

Quartz scheduler using in my applicationi i want to check the size the ram memory consumed by quartz schduler?

Answer (score 0):

In Java you cannot simply see how much memory given library/framework uses. I guess you have problems with memory consumption? If you are using `RAMJobStore` then all jobs and triggers are stored in memory. If you have hundreds of thousands of them, the amount of memory used will be significant (but not easily computable).

With `JDBCJobStore` the memory footprint will be minimal.